# How to mint nft using js

Tags: nft, mint

When I use umi, it return error related to signerIdentity method. I did research but there was no solution or document about it. When I use js sdk, it return this error:

[image]

This is the code:

[image]

This is how I init Metaplex instance:

[image]

Comment: Can you share how your Metaplex instance is being initialized?

Comment: I edited my question @Ademola

Answer (score 1):

you can use candymachine to mint NFT.
now candymachine v3 available.

there are three steps to mint nft using candy machine.

1. create candy machine
2. insert items to candy machine
3. mint

you can reference more details on https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/minting

Comment: I did follow this but It return "signerIdentity method" error. Do you have any examples?

Comment: please share your code or meet on skype.

Comment: Here is my code and it return "(0 , _metaplex_foundation_mpl_token_metadata__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.createNft) is not a function" error 
```    const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com").use(mplCandyMachine());
    const collectionUpdateAuthority = generateSigner(umi);
    const collectionMint = generateSigner(umi);
    await createNft(umi, {
      mint: collectionMint,
      authority: collectionUpdateAuthority,
      name: "..",
      uri: "...",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(9.99, 2), // 9.99%
      isCollection: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
```

Comment: can you please give me getting metaplex codes?
it seems like you've got error with metaplex identity.

Comment: I just import and use them

Comment: Do you have any examples that work?